# How can I count number of objects in a list with a unique property with linq/lambda?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

Let's say I have a

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Property1;
   //other properties
   //other properties
}
```

and then I have a

```
List<MyObject> objectList
```

Where `Property1` has one value for the first few items, another value for the next few items, etc. How can I count the distinct number of `MyObject`s based on `Property1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`.

```
objectList.GroupBy(o => o.Property1);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy.aspx

Comment: I didn't come up with it. :P LINQ is amazing stuff.